# Open terminal, execute command, and enter interactive mode

Tags: node.js

I am writing a home automation web app. I have music that streams from Google music to my speakers and I use vlc to output the sound. What I cannot do is seem to pause the song remotely. For example, cvlc url will open and stream the url, then it enters an interactive mode where pause can be typed and it will pause.

When I try to do this from my node.js app, nothing happens. It just continues to play.

```
var terminal = require('child_process').spawn('bash');

terminal.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});

terminal.on('exit', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});

terminal.stdin.write('cvlc "' + req.url +'" & \n');
terminal.stdin.write('pause');
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting a '\n' after you pause command:

```
terminal.stdin.write('pause\n');
```

Also, I am not familiar with cvlc, yet, if you start it in the BG, not sure that you can write to its stdin, hence it might ignore all in all your 'pause' command, did you try invoking it without the '&'?

Also, why start a bash and then run cvlc? Why not:

```
var terminal = require('child_process').spawn('cvlc');
```

Last but not least, are you sure the default path is sufficient?

Comment: Changed it to, var terminal = require('child_process'); term = terminal.spawn('cvlc',[req.url]); term.stdin.write('pause\n'); Still starts the song and then doesn't pause.

Comment: And the default path should be fine. If I run the same command in the straight terminal, it brings up a prompt that you can type pause,play,fast, and etc... Basically I want to be able to bring up the prompt and interact with it.

Comment: Do you get anything from the stdout? Btw, the stdout is a hex buffer, you better do: console.log(data.toString());

Comment: Yeah, I get what I entered [pause], it just doesn't do anything. I am trying to figure out a way to do something like spawn('xterm',['cvlc',req.url]) but it does nothing. If I do just spawn('xterm',['clvc']) it will bring up basic cvlc, but that doesn't help me as you can't enter urls after that. If I can get xterm to do it then maybe I can manipulate that.

Answer (score 0):

I never actually figured this out via terminal. Instead I used VLC's http server option and then did get requests to control pause and play.

Spawn:

```
  var term = spawn.spawn('cvlc',['-I', 'http',req.url,'localhost:8080']);
```

Pause:

```
 var req = http.get('http://:password@localhost:8080/requests/status.xml?command=pl_pause', function (r) {
    r.on('data', function () { /* do nothing */
    });
});
```

And Play:

```
  var reqd = http.get('http://:password@localhost:8080/requests/status.xml?command=pl_play', function (r) {
        r.on('data', function () { /* do nothing */
        });
        r.on('error', function (err) { /* do nothing */
            console.log(err)
        });
    });
```

Hope that helps someone with a VLC control problem. I was doing this through a headless Raspberry Pi. I was trying to avoid paying for a Chromecast for my speakers and succeeded.